# Drupal Panels/Views conflict

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7 along with the Panels and Views modules. I've got a view with a page display, but I want to place it in a panel/page. I need the view's display to be that of a page because it has exposed filters, and I can't rely solely on AJAX for the filters because of 508 standards compliance concerns.

However, because the paths of the panel and the view are the same, [the view takes precedence](http://drupal.org/node/923588), and the panel never shows up. How do I get the view working inside the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your view as a content pane instead of a page. Then on your panel insert the content pane. You can also look at something like http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere as a more general solution.